# Synthetic Touch Event in React

Tags: reactjs, touch-event, synthetic

With the following .js, resizing the text area in browser doesn't present any touch event type, although the other events work as expected.

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {currentEvent: "---"};
        this.update = this.update.bind(this)
    }

    update(e){
        this.setState({currentEvent: e.type})
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <textarea cols='30' rows='10' 
                    onKeyPress={this.update}
                    onCopy={this.update}
                    onDoubleClick={this.update}
                    onTouchStart={this.update}
                    onTouchMove={this.update}
                    onTouchEnd={this.update}
                    />
                <h1>{this.state.currentEvent}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically no browsers will trigger a `resize` event for `textarea`. Instead you have to listen for `mouseup` or `touchend` events which will happen after the user has resized. But since those events can also be triggered for simply clicking in the `textarea`, you might want to compare the new size of the element to the old size to determine if it was actually resized or not.